# Capistrano, Passenger deployment failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano, passenger

There is this app which has been upgraded from Rails 3 to 4. (In addition to upgraded from Capistrano 2 to 3). This is an app that was built, has worked fine for a couple years and now we are adding some features and updating things - but deployment is failing.

I've tried reinstalling gems, passenger apache module, various capistrano deployment configuration options (with sudo, without sudo, setting specific gem paths with default_env ) and working through various Capistrano upgrade documentation, guides, blog posts and other SO posts...

**Deployment errors**

When attempting to push the changes to the staging server the deployment keeps failing.

Here's the base error when running `cap staging deploy`:

```
/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'passenger' (>= 0) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
```

There must be some simple conflict / confusion with paths / sudo / rvmsudo and has taken more time than I'd like to admit debugging...

Initially I tried doing everything without sudo but wasn't getting success. According to the rvm documentation (https://rvm.io/integration/sudo) I tried editng the sudoers file.

So following rvm.io documentation I comment out `Default secure_path=...` and add `Default env_keep` and the following error occurs:

```
Exception while executing as user@example.org: sudo exit status: 127
sudo stdout: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

**gem env**

Output of `$ gem env` on the staging server:

```
    $ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-02-25 patchlevel 643) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/user/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643
     - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin
     - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/bin
     - /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /home/user/.rvm/bin
     - /home/user/.rvm/bin
```

**config/deploy/staging.rb**

```
# server-based syntax
# ======================
# Defines a single server with a list of roles and multiple properties.
# You can define all roles on a single server, or split them:

# server 'example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app db web}, my_property: :my_value
# server 'example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app web}, other_property: :other_value
# server 'db.example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{db}

set :stage, :staging

server "example.org", user: "user", roles: %w{web, app, db}


# role-based syntax
# ==================

# Defines a role with one or multiple servers. The primary server in each
# group is considered to be the first unless any  hosts have the primary
# property set. Specify the username and a domain or IP for the server.
# Don't use `:all`, it's a meta role.

role :app, %w{example.org}
role :web, %w{example.org}
role :db,  %w{example.org}
# role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}, my_property: :my_value
# role :web, %w{user1@primary.com user2@additional.com}, other_property: :other_value
# role :db,  %w{deploy@example.com}



# Configuration
# =============
# You can set any configuration variable like in config/deploy.rb
# These variables are then only loaded and set in this stage.
# For available Capistrano configuration variables see the documentation page.
# http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/
# Feel free to add new variables to customise your setup.



# Custom SSH Options
# ==================
# You may pass any option but keep in mind that net/ssh understands a
# limited set of options, consult the Net::SSH documentation.
# http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start
#
# Global options
# --------------
#  set :ssh_options, {
#    keys: %w(/home/rlisowski/.ssh/id_rsa),
#    forward_agent: false,
#    auth_methods: %w(password)
#  }
#
# The server-based syntax can be used to override options:
# ------------------------------------
# server 'example.com',
#   user: 'user_name',
#   roles: %w{web app},
#   ssh_options: {
#     user: 'user_name', # overrides user setting above
#     keys: %w(/home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa),
#     forward_agent: false,
#     auth_methods: %w(publickey password)
#     # password: 'please use keys'
#   }


set :rails_env, "staging"

set :application, "res.example.org"
set :repo_url,  "user@example.org:/home/user/webdocs/appname.git"
# set :repo_url,  "ssh://user@example.org:3699/home/user/webdocs/appname.git"


set :ssh_options, {
  port: 3699,
  verbose: :debug 
}

# set :rvm_map_bins, %w{gem rake ruby bundle rvmsudo}
set :rvm_map_bins, fetch(:rvm_map_bins, []).push('rvmsudo')
# set :rbenv_ruby, "2.0.0" 
set :port, 3699
set :scm, :git
set :pty, true
# set :use_sudo, true
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`
# set :user, 'user'
set :use_sudo, false #true
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/res"
set :branch, "staging"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :passenger_rvm_ruby_version, "2.0.0"

set :default_env, { 
      rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin',
      path: "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin:$PATH" 
    }

set :passenger_restart_with_sudo, true
set :log_level, :debug
# set :passenger_restart_with_sudo, true
set :passenger_environment_variables, { :path => '/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin:$PATH' }



=begin 
set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => 'home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/user/.rvm/bin:$PATH'
  #'PATH' => '/home/user/.rvm/gems/default/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/default@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/default/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin:$PATH'  
  #'PATH' => '/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin:$PATH'  
}
=end

#default_environment["GEM_PATH"] ="/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320"
# /home/bb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin:/home/bb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global/bin:/home/bb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin:/home/bb/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/bb/.cabal/bin:/home/bb/.xmonad/bin 
#default_environment["PATH"] = "/home/bb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin:/home/bb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global/bin:/home/bb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin:/home/bb/.rvm/bin:$PATH"


# role :web, "example.org"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
#role :app, "example.org"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
#role :db,  "example.org", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
#role :db,  "example.org"

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

#after "deploy", "deploy:bundle_gems"
#after "deploy:bundle_gems", "deploy:restart"

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do

  desc "Install gems"
    task :bundle_gems do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
       run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle install"
     end
   end

  desc "Setup sym links for uploads..."
  task :make_links do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      run "ln -s #{shared_path}/uploads/ #{deploy_to}/current/public/uploads"
    end
  end

  desc "Precompile assets...."
  task :precompile_assets do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle exec rake --trace assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=staging"
    end
  end

  # task :start do ; end
  # task :stop do ; end
=begin  
  desc "Restart App"
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
      # run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
    end
  end
=end
end

after "deploy", "deploy:make_links"

after "deploy", "deploy:bundle_gems"

# after "deploy", "deploy:precompile_assets"
```

**Capfile**

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

    # Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
    #
    # For documentation on these, see for example:
    #
    #   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
    #   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
    #   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
    #   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
    #   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
    #   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
    #
    require 'capistrano/rvm'
    # require 'capistrano/rbenv'
    # require 'capistrano/chruby'
    require 'capistrano/bundler'
    require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
    require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
    require 'capistrano/passenger'

    # Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
    Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

**deploy.rb**

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'appname'
set :repo_url, 'user@example.org:/home/user/webdocs/appname.git'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
# set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app_name'

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
set :log_level, :debug

set :stages, %w(staging production)
set :default_stage, "staging"
# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

Any suggestions / direction appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After more testing and further reviewing the Passenger & Capistrano documentation (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html & http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/ ) there were a few points of confusion resolved.

The gem installation of passenger was uninstalled. Then following the Passenger documentation, and starting over from scratch, Passenger was installed via the Ubuntu repositories / apt-get.

In addition, passwordless sudo access needed to be setup for the deploy user - and update the Capistrano deployment file accordingly.

Specifically making sure 
`set :passenger_restart_with_sudo, true` was set

So the `Could not find 'passenger' (>= 0)` error is now gone.

Capistrano deployment is getting further. Now it's just hanging up on my rake tasks which is a different issue to work out.

Comment: thank you, had a few hours of downtime because of this issue. once again capistrano seems to make my life harder.